# Need help identifying math game where equations let you move from room to room?

Tags: apple-ii, software, apple, identify-this-game

Can anyone help me find an old math game where equations let you move from room to room? I played the game on an Apple II back in middle school and I want to use it with my daughter to teach her math. The game had simple high-res line based graphics and would put up equations to solve when you tried to move around. The graphics were black and white first person perspective, similar to Mystery House. The math in the game was simple math, probably addition or multiplication, generally fill in the blank. I've got a working IIgs with 3.5 and 5.25" drives so I can run any Apple II release of the game. The copy I played was on a pirated disk so I don't know the name or publisher for the game.

Comment: I don't know the game you are looking for, but I remember that MECC did a lot of educational titles.  I'm just throwing that out in case it jogs a memory or helps narrow your search criteria.

Comment: @Geo... I did some digging in the archives without much luck. The copy of the game I saw was a pirate copy without an obvious publisher. I've looked at what Macgui and What is the Apple IIgs have for math games, maybe I should check Asimov next.

Comment: I recall playing something similar, though that was on the BBC micro at school.... might help in your search if it was cross-platform.

Comment: @Michael Does it sound like the same game described [here](https://forums.macrumors.com/threads/apple-ii-game-we-used-to-play-in-elementary-school.549952/)?

Comment: Teh only one I could come up is Gertrudes Secret https://www.mobygames.com/game/gertrudes-secrets, as it works much like described and on the Apple II, just not with equations but shapes and alike. Maybe browse the educational games library at A2OL to see if there's a title that sounds right to you? http://apple2online.com/index.php?p=1_55_Educational-Software-Library

Comment: That sounds very much like a game from Microzine. I only have a few volumes myself, and haven't seen that particular game, but it sure sounds like one Scholastic would have published.

Comment: This seems very similar to [Adventures in Math](https://www.pcjs.org/apps/pcx86/1983/adventmath/), but that’s a PC game...

Answer (score 1):

I will guess [Math Shop](http://www.his.com/~pshapiro/math.shop.html). There was also Algebra Shop.

In this game the player went from "shop" to shop serving customers by solving math problems. Each shop featured different types of math problems.

Algebra Shop can be downloaded here:

http://www.apple2online.com/web_documents/algebrashop.zip

Comment: I've looked at Math Shop and that is definitely not the game that I remember. For one the Math Shop graphics are much better than the game I played, and secondly the game I played required answering math questions to move between rooms, not to buy goods.